# Why do I see the message Failed to open EFI/ubuntu failed to load image EFI/ubuntu start_image() returnedinvalid parameters falling back to default

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

When the computer starts I see this message

Failed to open EFI/ubuntu failed to load image EFI/ubuntu start_image() returned invalid parameters falling back to default loader

before I see grub menu.

I'm running with dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11.

Both OS seem to be booting and running correctly.
How can I fix this, or not worry about it?

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu and I did not see the error until I booted to windows and back.

Comment: In your EFI partition, do you have the directory EFI/ubuntu?  What are its contents?  What image are you trying to boot from there?

Comment: @ubfan1 in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu  I have BOOTX64.CSV  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi  I don't know what I am trying to boot from Can I find that in grub.cfg

Comment: Those look normal. If grubx64.efi were missing, speculating that the message might make sense if the next boot attempt were to try the EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (the fallback/device bootloader) instead of the explicit second entry in the boot order. (and that fallback boot succeeded).

Comment: @ubfan1 I get what's happening, it doesn't explain why or what's broken and how to fix it. If bootx64 works, how do I put that 1st?

Comment: Boot the device, not an nvram entry, and you use the EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi bootloader.

Comment: @ubfan1 I'm sorry I don't understand "not an nvram entry"

Comment: The installed bootloaders are stored in various directories, and each has a non-volatile memory entry in the machine which remembers these entries, and puts them into the boot selection.  The device itself does not need such an entry, since its bootloader is always in the same place: EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (for x64 architecture).